# Photoshop CC 2021 "could not complete your request because of program error"

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, adobe-photoshop

After upgrade from Photoshop CC 2020 to 2021 (Windows 10 Pro), I was not able to open JPG files and got the "could not complete your request because of program error".

I did some research and most of the "fix" did not work for me (i.e. reset preferences, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I found a suggestion to disable the use of the GPU under preferences / performance (uncheck: Use Graphics Processor). That did work. It allowed me to open JPG files as usual.

Disabling the GPU use gave me an idea to update my video card drivers (nVidia Quatro 2000). I downloaded and installed the new drivers for the video card.

I went back to preferences and enabled the GPU use. Then I tested opening my JPG files again. All works!

I'm putting this here so if someone experiencing the "could not complete your request because of program error" when opening JPG files can try updating the video card drivers fix.

TL;DR: Update your video card drivers.

Comment: Glad you figured it, but that's one more reason I'll not be updating to 2021 until probably Feb or March 2021. I always like to let them find the bugs, not me.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is bad form but I was hoping to add something to this post for people with a similar (not exactly the same) problem. This post is what comes up when searching for the issue on superuser or google.

The similar problem I was getting is, EVERY action I took with photoshop led to "could not complete your request because of program error". Opening a file, starting a new file, going into preferences, even closing the program. Sometimes I'd also get "could not write to disk".

I found out this is because my PC is on a domain with folder redirection on, so when I attempt to install programs to the default directory... the important settings don't go to C:\users\myself\AppData. They save to \domainname\users\myself\AppData. But, for some reason Photoshop has difficulty reading that folder. Probably a permissions problem.

My workaround was this: Sign out of my domain account, and sign into the local administrator account. Install Photoshop under that account. Launches without a problem. Go to C:\users\administrator\appdata\ and copy the entire adobe folder to a separate location, let's say desktop. (actually, the entire adobe folder may be overkill if you don't have issues with other adobe apps. I'm not sure if they have this problem. Maybe just copy the photoshop folder within Adobe).

Then, switch back to the domain account (close out of PS if it's open). Run regedit. Navigate to this key: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Photoshop\150.0

Then go to this entry: SettingsFilePath ... double click it... change the path from the domain path, to a local path like this: C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\Adobe Photoshop 2021 Settings\

Finally, navigate to that Roaming folder, and copy and paste the Adobe folder you backed up earlier, the one that was originally under users\administrator\appdata.

By changing this path setting, and moving the known-working files to that path, I was able to get Photoshop to launch properly again while logged into the domain.

Comment: Later, I found a simpler fix: You can run photoshop as a different user.

Ensure the secondary logon service is running. run powershell and paste this command: Get-Service seclogon

Now do the shortcut Windows+R to bring up a run dialogue. Use the runas command to run photoshop under whatever user account works properly.

runas /user:administrator "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\photoshop.exe"

No more hanging at "loading preferences" or "could not complete your request" issues.